# in advantage of and in favour of meaning

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-meaning

**I lost my business in advantage of a competitor.**

I want to say that a competitor will benefit from losing my business.

**We should not avoid teaching music in favour of other school subjects.**

I want to say that we should not prefer teaching other school classes rather than music.

Am I using these phrases correctly? I look into dictionary and either did not find the word or the usage is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is actually quite good. It is grammatically correct and conveys your thought clearly. Alternative ways of communicating the same idea would be:

- *We shouldn't favor teaching other subjects over music.*
- *Music shouldn't be valued less than other subjects.*

The first sentence isn't correct. You cannot use "*in advantage of*" like that. If you wish to say that losing your business would benefit your competitors, here are a few sentences similar to your original that you could use to express this:

- *Losing my business would be advantageous for my competitors.*
- *It would be to the advantage of my competitors if I lost my business.*
- *My competitors would benefit from me losing my business.*
- *It would benefit my competitors for me to lose my business.*
- *My competitors would benefit from my business failing.*